# Define last index of element in text with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have such construction:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line=sr.ReadLine();
                fullTextLines.Add(line);
            }
```

and some text:

```
string txt = "begin

middle

i am a string          

i am a string end"
```

I want to get last line index which consist "i am".For example: I must get 3 but when I used `Console.WriteLine(fullTextLines.LastIndexOf("GRID"));` I got -1.

Comment: what is `fullTextLines`? string builder?

Comment: it's private List<string> fullTextLines = new List<string>();

Comment: @JW I would guess `List<string>`

Comment: `LastIndexOf("GRID")` and you talk about "i am"... don't sure I understand

Comment: Your text does not contain "GRID"; why would you expect `LastIndexOf("GRID")` to be anything other than -1? Also: your text does not contain any strings equaling "i am"...

Comment: I've mistake.It must be "i am"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = File.ReadLines(fileName)
                 .Select((s,i) => new { Line = s, Index = i })
                 .LastOrDefault(x => x.Line.Contains("i am"));

int index = result == null ? -1 : result.Index;
```

Comment: Possible `NullReferenceException` when there is no element with `i am`

Comment: `File.ReadLines` would be even better

Comment: @MarcGravell agree :) always forget about new methods

Answer (score 6):

```
fullTextLines.FindLastIndex(x => x.Contains("i am"));
```

Comment: That's great! Never heard about that method before.

Comment: Yes, if you have list of lines, than this is best approach

Answer (score 1):

```
var lastIAmIndex = fullTextLines.Select((s,i) => new { s, i })
                                .Where(e => e.s.Contains("i am"))
                                .Select(e => e.i)
                                .OrderByDescending(i => i)
                                .FirstOrDefault()
```